# Most received mails are marked as spam

Tags: email, smtp, spam, gmail

I use Google Mail for all my personal mails.
I use a custom mail address which is configured to forward all mails to my Google Mail account.
When sending mails I use the feature to use another smtp server.
All my custom mail addresses are hosted at yandex.

Now to the problem: Google Mail is marking all *incoming* mails to my email address (`"something"@jakobjarosch.de`) as *spam*.

In Google Mail it looks like the following:
[image: google mail inbox]

This happens for nearly all mails I receive, except mails from another Google Mail account.

I hope someone can help me out why this is caused, therefore here are some more details about an example mail I received:

```
Message ID  <2413721486894709@web43j.yandex.ru>
Created at: Sun, Feb 12, 2017 at 11:18 AM (Delivered after 1 seconds)
From:   Jakob Jarosch <"firstname.lastname"@yandex.com>
To: "something"@jakobjarosch.de
Subject:    Test-Mail
SPF:    PASS with IP 5.255.227.236
DKIM:   PASS with domain yandex.com
DMARC:  PASS
```

And here the full mail dump: http://pastebin.com/raw/q8QUff06

I'm a bit surprised because the mail passes SPF, DKIM and DMARC and is nevertheless marked as spam.

I tried it with sending mails from:

- other Gmail accounts [no spam]
- My work mail account [spam]
- A yandex mail account [spam]
- IsMyEmailWorking.com [spam]
- A german mail hoster (web.de [spam]
- Another company mail account [spam]

Another curious thing is, this happens for mails to `"something"@jakobjarosch.de` and `"something"@foxylion.de`, but not for mails to `"something"@jakob.soy`. The configuration is the same for all of the three domains (or at least should be).

I would appreciate any help. I've no more ideas especially because it also happens for mails where SPF, DKIM and DMARC are working.

Comment: ANything? I am facing same problem.